# Essentials "worth.yml" inconsistency

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to set prices for all items in the Essentials plugin's "worth.yml" config file.
The server is running 1.11.2.
**Only some items in the config are recognized, and I don't see the problem.**

For example, the line for beacon in config is

> beacon: 15000.0

and the game responds correctly, when asked "/price beacon",

[image]

The line for iron horse armor is

> ironhorsearmor: 44.0

but when asked "/price ironhorsearmor" (a valid name in essentials), the game answers

[image]

**Why are some items unrecognized?**

- All prices across the file are configued the same way
- "Working" items "work" for /price, /buy, and /sell
- "Broken" items do not work for /price, /buy, or /sell
- Examples of working items are beacons, stone, all clay colors, saplings
- Examples of broken items are carrots, all horse armors, all dye colors

[**The whole file can be found here**](https://pastebin.com/V4puN69L)

Comment: What Essentials version do you use?

Comment: I remember a couple of years back when I was attempting to create my Minecraft server when Essentials was messing me about. I found that the only way to really fix the problem was to scrap the full file and start again. The following this could be potential problems: whitespace in the wrong place, syntax errors (missing symbols, incorrect usage, etc) and defining the same thing more than once.

Comment: With my comment below in mind (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307525/essentials-worth-yml-inconsistency#comment436207_307780), having a look at the official `worth.yml` by Spigot, it may not be possible to sell `ironhorsearmor` due to the fact it isn't there (for reference?).

Comment: Perhaps try IHorseArmor. As stuff such as DPickaxe works (In most cases)

Comment: @Zxyrra If you could give me a link to where you downloaded it I could download it and play around with it and try and find you an answer.

Comment: @Zxyrra Your problem may be your server version, after looking for essentials I found it in a couple places and almost all of them say there is no essentials for minecraft 1.8 and apparently the current essentials works for minecraft 1.7.9 not 1.11.2 so that may be your problem.

Comment: @Zxyrra try running it on minecraft 1.7.9 then see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

I  believe the problem from what I saw is that the official Minecraft id for iron horse armor is:

> **iron_horse_armor**

And not,

> **ironhorsearmor**

so I believe this is the problem I would suggest changing this and trying it again. If that doesn't fix it then its probably the actual mod and I would need to see it.

Plus if this does fix it then you will need to change the other horse armors as well.

[Minecraft Id List](http://minecraft-ids.grahamedgecombe.com/)

Comment: I am willing to try this but hesitant - essentials takes about a million names when using /price, *including* "ironhorsearmor" so I'm confused as to why only one would be valid in config.

Comment: @Zxyrra Well try it and tell me if it works. Plus if it breaks you can always change it back.

Comment: @Zxyrra Can you also give me a link to where you downloaded the mod so I can actually look at the mod.

Comment: @Zxyrra Also another way to find out if its actually a problem with iron horse armor is to do **/price goldhorsearmor** and see if you get an error from that.

Comment: @Emptyisme: Looking at the list you provided, you can see that Diamond Ore has an id of `diamond_ore` but you can see on line 110 in the official `worth.yml`, Diamond Ore has the id of `diamondore`. Link to the Spigot docs https://github.com/SpigotMC/SpigotCraft/blob/master/plugins/Essentials/worth.yml#L110

Comment: As i can see, this is not added by default. This solution should work @Zxyrra

Comment: I am working on rewriting the names now but this answer seems invalid. "spruce_boat" is the correct item ID and is written correctly yet it will not sell on the server.

Comment: This is not correct. All config IDs are now either accepted by essentials regardless of MC ID (ones like leatherhelmet are still OK and will sell) or up to MC ID if not otherwise recognized. Still no change in sellage.

Comment: @Zxyrra Can you give me a link to the rest of the mod, so I can look at it?

Comment: @Zxyrra I really can't help you any further without seeing the actual mod so, either give me a link to were you downloaded the mod so I can download it and look at it or I really cannot help you any further.

Comment: @Emptyisme I don't know where it's from but look up "essentials" and it will be the most recent update.

Comment: @Zxyrra when I look up essentials I find it released from around 15 different sources and all of them say there is no official so I kinda can't just search for the most recent update. Sorry gtg for a couple hours please see if you can find the link in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

As about everyone has said, it's iron_horse_armor, and Not IronHorseArmor. It is a "bug" with essentials that it will look for anything, even if it's not in Minecraft's code. This is especially for mods (iirc). If you have said the price, and then do

> /sell hand

And if it doesn't work, you have the wrong ID.

Also, The ID of Carrot is

> Carrots

As just Carrot, without an S is the crop, that grows on Soil.

The Dye Color IDs are not like INK but instead are

> dye:1-14.

(If this doesn't work tell me so I can see if there's more IDs for Dye)
(INK_SACK just might work though, but there's no such thing as just: blue)

It's the same with spawn eggs, There's no such thing as:

> zombiespawnegg

But instead it is:

> spawn_egg:1

(I don't know what the Zombie ID is, 1 should be pig.) Even though IT MIGHT BE possible that essentials has changed this and the ID has changed to: pigspawnegg, for example.

Comment: This is incorrect. All IDs are either now up to Essentials' standards (like DPickaxe) or MC standard (iron_horse_armor) and there has been no change in what can be sold.